Using Gauss-Bonnet to Show Compact Connected 2-D Lie Group is Isomorphic to Torus
I'm working on the following problem from Lee's Intro to Riemannian Manifolds:

Use the Gauss-Bonnet theorem to prove that every compact connected Lie group of dimension 2 is isomorphic to the direct product group $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$. [Hint: See Problem 8-17.]

Lee already referred to a result from Intro to Topological Manifolds that every compact, connected, orientable 2-manifold is homeomorphic either to a sphere or to a connected sum of $n$-tori, which I'll accept without proof. With the (possibly erroneous) assumption that this extends to diffeomorphism in the case of smooth manifolds, showing that the Lie group (which I'll call $G$) has Euler characteristic 0 will at least then give me a diffeomorphism with the torus.
I know that because $G$ is compact it admits a bi-invariant metric. Thus, the problem referred to in the hint tells me that for any $X, Y \in \mathrm{Lie}(G)$, sec$(X_p, Y_p) = \frac14 |[X, Y]|^2$. Further, because $G$ is 2-dimensional, the sectional curvature is exactly the scalar curvature $S$, which in turn is twice the Gaussian curvature $K$. Putting that all together, the Gauss-Bonnet theorem then gives me
$$
  \chi(G) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_G K \,dA = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_G \frac18 |[X, Y]|^2 \,dA.
 $$
Thus, in order for the Euler characteristic to vanish, the Lie bracket in the integrand must vanish; that is, Lie$(G)$ must be abelian. But because $G$ is connected, this is equivalent to $G$ being abelian.
I've found a proof here that compact connected complex Lie groups are abelian, but I don't know if it can be adapted to generic compact connected Lie groups. And beyond that, I don't know how to show that the desired diffeomorphsim between $G$ and the torus is also a group homomorphism.
What do I need here?

From the formula of Problem 8-17 and Gauss-Bonnet theorem it follows that $\chi(G) \ge 0$. There are only two (up to a diffeomorphism) compact connected orientable two-dimensional manifolds with nonnegative Euler characteristic: sphere and torus. It is easy to see that sphere cannot be endowed with a Lie group structure (for instance, you may note that all Lie groups admit vector fields that nowhere vanish, and sphere does not). Therefore, $G$ is diffeomorphic to a torus and, in particular, $\chi(G) = 0$. This in turn implies that the integrand in the Gauss-Bonnet formula is zero (since it is nonnegative), so Lie algebra of $G$ is Abelian. As $G$ is connected we conclude that $G$ is also Abelain. It remains to note that compact Abelian connected Lie group of dimension $n$ is always isomorphic to a product of $n$ circles.

Ah, so the hairy ball theorem saves the day! I don't remember ever reading explicitly that Lie groups have nowhere vanishing vector fields, but it's easy to see that since left translation is a diffeomorphism then every nonzero left-invariant vector field is nonvanishing. Thank you so much for your help!
